# How To Install Python Scatterer T-matrix module on Colab?

Tags: matrix, installation, module, google-colaboratory, term-document-matrix

How do I install the module for the t-matrix scatterer on google colab woking with window OS?

Module Not found error After running the line:
`import pytmatrix`

See Error below:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytmatrix'`

Tried using the pip install method here before importing the library
but got the error below.
 `!pip install pytmatrix`

See Error below:

```
Collecting pytmatrix
  Downloading pytmatrix-0.3.3.tar.gz (55 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 55.7/55.7 kB 1.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```